# MVC 4.5 DataBind HTML to Dictionary, posting to object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary, data-binding

New to c# and mvc, so I'm confused as to why in these two examples, only one of them works.  I'm checking this by just adding a breakpoint and inspecting the object.

**View (Same for both examples)**

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Post", "Delivery")" method="post">
        <table class="table" id="table">
            <tbody>
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var line in Model.TransactionLines)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@line.StockCode</td>
                            <td>@line.Location</td>
                            <td>@line.Qty</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" name="@("MoveOut[" + line.TranID + "]")" value="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

### Working:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Post(Dictionary<string, string> MoveOut)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Saved");
}
```

### Not Working:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Post(DeliveryModel Delivery)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Saved");
}
```

**Model**

```
public class DeliveryModel : ReceiptModel
{
    //Also tried below
    //public Dictionary<string, string> MoveOut;
    public Dictionary<string, string> MoveOut = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

Comment: You model does not have a property, just a field (no `get; set;`) so the value of `MoveOut` cannot be **set**

Comment: Ah! `public Dictionary<string, string> MoveOut { get; set; }` worked.  @StephenMuecke want to make that an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DeliveryModel` only has a field for `MoveOut`, not a property with a getter and setter so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** the value. Change it to

```
public class DeliveryModel : ReceiptModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MoveOut { get; set; }
}
```